# Lightning Strike Event Handling

Tags: java, events, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to figure out how to get lightning to strike whenever I throw an egg. My code isn't giving me any errors however the console is. The message still pops up but the lightning does not.

```
package me.sanfrinsisco;

import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEggThrowEvent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class PlayerListener implements Listener {

    public PlayerListener(EventHandling plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPickup(PlayerEggThrowEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "You have summoned lightning");

        e.setHatchingType(EntityType.LIGHTNING);
        e.setNumHatches((byte) 1);
        e.setHatching(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting in my console

```
[19:37:58 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerEggThrowEvent to EventHandling v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:500) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:485) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.EntityEgg.a(EntityEgg.java:51) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.EntityProjectile.B_(EntityProjectile.java:167) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.World.entityJoinedWorld(World.java:1633) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.World.h(World.java:1603) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.World.tickEntities(World.java:1437) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.WorldServer.tickEntities(WorldServer.java:665) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:817) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:406) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:679) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:577) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't spawn that entity type from an egg!
        at org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerEggThrowEvent.setHatchingType(PlayerEggThrowEvent.java:70) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        at me.sanfrinsisco.PlayerListener.onPickup(PlayerListener.java:22) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-f46ccd7]
        ... 14 more
>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't spawn that entity type from an egg!` - Looks like you can't set eggs to hatch lightning directly

Comment: Okay so instead of spawning the lightning from the egg itself. I'm going to store its location in an integer and spawn lightning at that specific location. I'm how sure how to go about spawning the lightning, I've been looking everywhere. Here's what I changed it too:

' @EventHandler
 public void onPickup(PlayerEggThrowEvent e, Egg egg) {
  Player player = e.getPlayer();
  
  e.setHatching(false);
  
  Location eggloc = egg.getLocation();
  
  player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "You have summoned lightning");
 }
}'
**For some reason I can't format the code in the comment.**

Answer (score 2):

As cleverly stated already, you can't set eggs to hatch lightning. However we can achieve  the same effect using a world and location:

```
@EventHandler
public void onProjectileHit(PlayerEggThrowEvent event) {
    Egg egg = event.getEgg();
    egg.getWorld().strikeLightningEffect(egg.getLocation());
    event.setHatching(false);
}
```

If you use `strikeLightningEffect`, the lightning doesn't light anything, if you use  `strikeLightning`, it does.

In the future, consider reading through the stacktraces/errors, they are not your foes, quite opposite actually!

This does not have anything to do with your problem, but consider changing your ChatColor import to bukkit's one instead of bungeecord unless you are using bungeecord, otherwise this might lead to eventual future problems.